# Slice and bounce effect not working properly in pie chart

Tags: d3.js

As per below code I am expecting `bounce effect` when the `pie chart loads` for the `first time` which do not work as expected and `expand the arc slice` when `on mouseenter` but slicing the selected arc overlaps the adjacent arcs while it should work as `red arc` as in the below example it should only expand and displace other arcs. Can any give pointer on where exactly I am doing wrong.

Pie Chart

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10;


var data=[
  {
    "age": "<5",
    "population": 2704659
  },
  {
    "age": "5-13",
    "population": 4499890
  },
  {
    "age": "14-17",
    "population": 2159981
  },
  {
    "age": "18-24",
    "population": 3853788
  },
  {
    "age": "25-44",
    "population": 14106543
  },
  {
    "age": "45-64",
    "population": 8819342
  },
  {
    "age": "≥65",
    "population": 612463
  }
];
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius);



var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

  var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); }).on("mouseenter", function(d) {
     var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.2;
             var startAngle = d.startAngle - 0.2;
   var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius + 10).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
            d3.select(this)
               .attr("stroke","white")
               .transition()
               .ease("bounce")
               .duration(1000)
               .attr("d", arcOver)             
               .attr("stroke-width",6);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).transition()            
               .attr("d", arc)
               .attr("stroke","none");
        })
  .transition()
    .ease("bounce")
    .duration(2000)
    .attrTween("d", tweenPie).attr("d", arc);

function tweenPie(b) {
  b.innerRadius = 0;
  var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
}

arcs.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/caqihu/edit?html,output) of what I have tried so far.

Comment: Why do you have  `.attr("d", arc);` after  `.attrTween("d", tweenPie)`?

Comment: Thanks that fixed my bounce issue I didn't realize from where that crept in. However the issue with `highlighting` the `arc slice` on `mouseenter` still persists.

Comment: Baby steps, one problem at a time! :-)

Comment: Now regarding the arcs: that behaviour of the red arc happens because it's the first one. We are talking about something like z index here: to have the same effect for all the slices, you'll have to remove the arc and re append it as the last child.

Comment: But if you see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8huvuoj9/4/) here `orange, cream and green` all three work perfectly . It would have failed if that was case of adding/removing from first. And if I redraw then then I would get a flicker where svg is removed and redrawn.

Comment: Not "last child", sorry, "first child" is what I mean. I updated the code and wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcs overlap because of the order they were appended in the SVG. As you know, the SVG order defines what element goes over its siblings. So, when you expand the hovered arc (using the new startAngle and endAngle), the arc expands *under* a sibling that sits on top of it in the SVG order.

One solution is sorting the elements inside the `mouseenter` function, in such a way that the hovered element is the first one in the SVG order. This is the function:

```
  svg.selectAll("path").sort(function (a, b) { 
      if (a != d) return -1;               
      else return 1;                             
  });
```

The element that you hovered is the `d`, and `a` is the first one. Using this function, all the `paths` are sorted when you hover over them.

This is the Bin: http://jsbin.com/hotifepiko/1/edit?html,output

PS: This other Bin solves the problem of the disappearing texts (because of the `sort` function). I just created new groups for the texts: http://jsbin.com/mifejasiyo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly but on hover over right side semi circle of the pie the text disappears(i.e. orange,cream and light blue ).

Comment: Indeed, whe `sort` was removing the text inside the `g` elements. A temporary solution is creating other `g` elements for the texts, check the bin: http://jsbin.com/mifejasiyo/1/edit?html,output